# WPF Toolkit RichTextBox FontSize Binding

Tags: c#, wpf, wpftoolkit

I have a RichTextBox from the WPFToolkit in a form with other controls including a textbox and I'm binding FontFamily and FontSize to both controls. My combobox selects each FontFamily and FontSize and the Textbox dynamically changes both but the RichTextBox does not.

I've tried both binding to type of Double & String and get the same result.

```
                <ComboBox Name="cmbFontFamily" 
                        ItemsSource="{Binding FontList}" 
                        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                        SelectedItem="{Binding FontFamilySet, Mode=TwoWay}"  
                        Margin="5,0,0,0"
                        Grid.Row="0" 
                        Grid.Column="4" 
                        Grid.ColumnSpan="1" 
                        Height="30"
                        Width="125"
                        />
                <ComboBox Name="cmbFontFamilySize" 
                        ItemsSource="{Binding FontSizeList}" 
                        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                        SelectedItem="{Binding FontSizeSet, Mode=TwoWay}"  
                        Margin="145,0,0,0"
                        Grid.Row="0" 
                        Grid.Column="4" 
                        Grid.ColumnSpan="1" 
                        Height="30"
                        Width="75"
                        />


            </Grid>
            <TabControl Name="tabControlCertLetterDesign" Height="750" Width="Auto" BorderBrush="Blue">
                <TabItem Header="Defieciency Letter" Name="DefieciencyTab" BorderBrush="Blue" Foreground="Blue" BorderThickness="3">
                    <ScrollViewer Width="Auto" Height="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" >
                        <Grid x:Name="LayOutRoot">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="10" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="300" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="800" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="15" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="52*" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="80"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="80"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="80"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="80"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="80"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="80"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="80"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="80"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="80"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="80"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="80"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="80"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="80"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="80"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="80"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="80"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="80"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="80"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                            <Label  Content="{Binding LabelList, Converter={StaticResource FormLabelConverter}, ConverterParameter='reLabel'}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,10,0"/>
                            <TextBox Text="{Binding CurrentCertGenLetterTempl.Re, Mode=TwoWay}"  Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" FontFamily="{Binding FontFamilySet}" FontSize="{Binding FontSizeSet}"/>

                            <Label  Content="{Binding LabelList, Converter={StaticResource FormLabelConverter}, ConverterParameter='body1Label'}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,10,0"/>
                            <toolkit:RichTextBox Text="{Binding CurrentCertGenLetterTempl.Body1, Mode=TwoWay}"  Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="3" Height="Auto" MinWidth="400" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"  AcceptsTab="True" FontFamily="{Binding FontFamilySet}" FontSize="{Binding FontSizeSet}" />

                            <Label  Content="{Binding LabelList, Converter={StaticResource FormLabelConverter}, ConverterParameter='body2Label'}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="4" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,10,0"/>
                            <toolkit:RichTextBox Text="{Binding CurrentCertGenLetterTempl.Body2, Mode=TwoWay}" Grid.Column="2"  Grid.Row="4" Height="Auto" MinWidth="400" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"  AcceptsTab="True" FontFamily="{Binding FontFamilySet}" FontSize="{Binding FontSizeSet}"/>

    private string fontFamilySet;
    public string FontFamilySet
    {
        get
        {
            return fontFamilySet;
        }
        set
        {
            if ((fontFamilySet != value))
            {
                fontFamilySet = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("FontFamilySet");
            }
        }
    }


    private double fontSizeSet;
    public double FontSizeSet
    {
        get
        {
            return fontSizeSet;
        }
        set
        {
            if ((fontSizeSet != value))
            {
                fontSizeSet = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("FontSizeSet");
                OnPropertyChanged("CurrentCertGenLetterTempl");
            }
        }
    }
```

In this code example only the TextBox is dynamically controlled by the Combobpxes but not the RichTextBox.

Comment: I think that the fontfamily of richtextbox is not a string. Use: <ComboBox 
                Name="SelectedFontFamily"
                ItemsSource="{Binding Source={x:Static Fonts.SystemFontFamilies}}"> And Bind to its selectedvalue as:             <RichTextBox FontFamily="{Binding ElementName=SelectedFontFamily, Path=SelectedValue}">

Comment: it is of type FontFamily and not a string. Check the comment after being edited and reply pls.

Comment: Binding the FOntFamily as a string actually works fine. it;s the FontSizeSet binding that is only working on the TextBox and not the RichTextBox. I've tried binding the FontSizeSet as a double and a string with the same results.

Comment: so bind thefont size to your property, and convert it via a converter

Comment: I've tried a converter on the FontSizeSet and it doesn't work for either as a String or Double type.so, is the conclusion that I should be able to bind a Font Size to a RichTextbox?